# searching/updating data in different tables with same ID (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

i need some help for mysql stuffs.

i have a main database SE, inside the database i have around 7 different tables.

all of the tables have records of different people with their unique identification number ID 'Sxxxxxxxx'.

i need to update/display my query to 3 of my tables with that particular ID.
for example

A) **Info_ID** | one | two | 
B) **Info_ID** | three | four| 
C) **Info_ID** | five | six | 
D) **Info_ID** | seven | eight|  
E) **Info_ID** | nine | ten |

all of the different table have a record of ID S1234567A as Info_ID.

i would like to update to

table A, column **two** with data **"hello"** 
table C, column **six** with data **"testing"** 
table E, column **ten** with data **"updates"**

all of them to the ID number S1234567A

i am new to this web, i hope that you guys could understand me and help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your table structure and expected result more clearly? Try doing it in excel or smthg and using [this](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Comment: Please don't tag your question with both sql-server and mysql - which RDBMS is this?

Answer (score 0):

Update and Display will require two totally different approaches

For the update, AFAIK you have no option other than to do 3 separate update statements:

```
update A set Col2 = 'hello' 
where info_id = 'S1234567A';
update C set Col6 = 'testing' 
where info_id = 'S1234567A';
update E set Col10 = 'ten' 
where info_id = 'S1234567A';
```

For the query side, you can combine the result

```
select A.Col1, ACol2, C.Col5, C.Col6, E.Col9, E.Col10
from 
   A inner join C
     on A.info_id = C.info_id
   inner join E
     on A.info_id = E.info_id
where 
   A.info_id = 'S1234567A';
```

If the column pairings (A.Col1, C.Col5 and E.Col9) and (A.Col2, C.Col6 and E.Col10) are compatable, you can also aggregate them in a union.

```
select 
   A.Col1 as FirstColumn, ACol2 as SecondColumn
from 
   A 
where 
   A.info_id = 'S1234567A'

union

select 
   C.Col5, C.Col6
from 
   C 
where 
   C.info_id = 'S1234567A'

union

select 
   E.Col9, E.Col10
from 
   E 
where 
   E.info_id = 'S1234567A';
```